# How to get a Chinese motorcycle driver's license with 1 year (90 days entry) visa?

Tags: driving-license, china

I don't have any licence currently, because I lost mine. How can I get driving a gas scooter  ASAP? I don't mind "quick" way. I heard there are options to buy a set on taobao - plates, licence and docs. Anybody know anything

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get a Chinese driver's license, when on a Chinese Q2 visa?](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2599/is-it-possible-to-get-a-chinese-drivers-license-when-on-a-chinese-q2-visa)

Answer (score 2):

Any type of visa is ok, but for a motorcycle driving license, the visa must be >90 days (continuous ... i.e., each stay must be at least 90 days).

I'm gonna leave this website with more info about the motorcycle requirement and driving license, it's too long to post it here

http://www.thebeijinger.com/forum/2012/05/11/motorcycles-beijing-fact-versus-fiction

http://www.mychinamoto.com/