# Obtaining China Driver's License with Other Country's Expired License

Tags: driving-license, china, driving

This [answer](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/3093/5968) lists out the requirements for a Chinese driver's license saying:

> You will need your ... driver's license from your country in original and copy

Does it matter if said license is expired?

Answer (score 1):

An expired original driver's license is going to be of zero help to you. A, current, valid driver's license is needed in order to get your foreign license off of your originals merits.

Comment: How do you know this? Heard it through the grapevine? Personal experience?

Comment: I tired using my old expired license to apply for a foreign one and failed miserably.