# Renew Chinese driving license on a Q2 visa

Tags: visa, driving-license, china

I am holding a Chinese driving license that I got at the time I was living in China with a residence permit.

The driving license is about to expire but at present I hold a Q2 visa (my spouse is Chinese but I am working outside China).

Can I still renew the driving license I hold, showing the Q2 visa next time I go to China? Or it is mandatory to have a residence permit or another visa?

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this answer to a related question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/3093/12159), it is possible to get a Chinese driving license on a Q2 visa as long as you have your proof of address in China. I therefore suppose it should certainly also be possible to renew your existing license.